# Optimized code for mysql insert query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i am writing a module for inserting data in MySQL table. It is very easy but in my module i am receiving four mobile number. The first one is user's mobile no and other three are reference mobile number. User's mobile no is mandatory field but reference are not. this time i am checking each reference mobile no by using `isset()` and `empty()` function in PHP.
but i have to write multiple if-else block. like

```
if(isset($_POST['mobileno_1']) && !empty($_POST['mobileno_1'])){
        $mobileno1 = $_POST['mobileno_1'];
    }else{
        $mobileno1 = 0;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['mobileno_2']) && !empty($_POST['mobileno_2'])){
        $mobileno2 = $_POST['mobileno_2'];
    }else{
        $mobileno2 = 0;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['mobileno_3']) && !empty($_POST['mobileno_3'])){
        $mobileno3 = $_POST['mobileno_3'];
    }else{
        $mobileno3 = 0;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO refferencemobile(mobileno, mobile1, mobile2, mobile3) VALUES($mobileno, $mobileno1, $mobileno2, $mobileno3)";
```

is there any optimized way to do this.so that it can reduce number of if-else block.

Answer (score 2):

`empty` already checks if a variable isset so this simplifies the if statments.

You can also use ternary conditions. These look like:

```
$someCondition ? 'a' : 'b';
```

Which will evaluate to 'a' if `$someCondition` is true and 'b' otherwise.

Putting this together we can get:

```
    //If $_POST['mobileno_1'] isset and has a non false value use $_POST['mobileno_1']
    $mobileno1 = !empty($_POST['mobileno_1']) ? $_POST['mobileno_1'] : 0;
    $mobileno2 = !empty($_POST['mobileno_2']) ? $_POST['mobileno_2'] : 0;
    $mobileno3 = !empty($_POST['mobileno_3']) ? $_POST['mobileno_3'] : 0;
```

As user1281385 pointed out in the comments you are using posted values directly in a query. You need to make sure these are sanitised or, better yet, use prepared statements.

Comment: +1, but remember to check mobileno_1 2 and 3 for safe query strings also.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$mobileno3 = (isset($_POST['mobileno_3']) && !empty($_POST['mobileno_3']))
    ? $_POST['mobileno_3']
    : 0;
```

You can even turn it into a function.

```
function GetMobileNo($mobileNo)
{
    return (isset($mobileNo) && !empty($mobileNo)) ? $mobileNo : 0;
}

$mobileno3 = GetMobileNo($_POST['mobileno_3']);
```

Answer (score 0):

sample/test code here http://codepad.org/5ybUcmcN

```
$mobileno1 = getMobileNo($_POST['mobileno_1']);
$mobileno2 = getMobileNo($_POST['mobileno_2']);
$mobileno3 = getMobileNo($_POST['mobileno_3']);

/* example 
$mobileno1 = getMobileNo('abc');
$mobileno2 = getMobileNo('111');
$mobileno3 = getMobileNo('');
*/

 $sql = "INSERT INTO refferencemobile(mobileno, mobile1, mobile2, mobile3) VALUES($mobileno, $mobileno1, $mobileno2, $mobileno3)";

function getMobileNo($mobileNo){

   // check for if its set or not OR empty OR not an integer
   if(!isset($mobileNo) || empty($mobileNo) || !is_int($mobileNo)){
      return 0;
   }   

   return $mobileNo; // valid number 
}
```

Comment: i would use ctype_digit here rather than is_int, is_int will always fail due to post vars being strings

Comment: avoid is_numeric too as it allows decimal points and scientific notation

Comment: looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php, i see is_numeric seems more suitable.

Comment: below case  ctype_digit donot help

$integer        = 42;
ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)

Comment: or we can use something similar if (filter_var($_POST['mobileNo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) ...

Comment: Yes because your passing an int to ctype_digit which converts to ascii. You should be passing a string from the form. Not an int which you defined. If you wanted to pass an int you would need to cast as string first ctype_digit((string)$var) for example